# CSS increase height from zero when tabbing into focus

Tags: css, focus, height

If I have a div that I've "hidden" by setting height to zero, is it possible to give it height when a user tabs into the field? Currently I can tab into it and type in the field, if I expand it with javascript you can see what was keyed into the field when height was still set to zero.

Comment: Why not?...but I suspect **we'll need to see your implementation**. This *should* be relatively simple.

Comment: Have you tried styling the `:focus` pseudo selector of that div? i.e `div.hidden:focus{ height: 50px; }`

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need to set a `tabindex` to be able to `:focus` on a div...but without seeing the code it's hard to offer suggestions.

Comment: also unsure of what _"if I expand it with javascript you can see what was keyed into the field when height was still set to zero"_ means. We need to see some code

Comment: I didn't add code because we have cross-origin iframes nested in the div in question. It seems that input is what is taking the focus. I'll try styling that.

Answer (score 0):

For an input element you could achieve it via CSS, with something like:

```css
input {
  height: 0px;
  border: 0;
  background: transparent;
  transition: all .3s linear;
}

input:focus {
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<p> Click anywhere in snippet window first, then tab with keyboard</p>
<input type="text">
```